# ASP.Net MVC FileStreamResult to load PDF in HTML Object.Data works in VS 2010 Debug mode and not in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, filestreamresult, html-object

In our application we need to get the PDF from Application and should be displayed on IE9[8 or 7], Application is in ASP.Net MVC 3, the PDF file is coming from SSRS, based on user criteria SSRS will return PDF and that to be shown on browser in  tag.

Things work perfect when we run application in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010 and application hosted in IIS7.5.
But as soon as we access application without debugger, PDF don't get rendered or loaded in Object Tag, not even Adobe AtiveX PDF Viewer appears.

So to figure out what is the issue, from IE9 developer toolbar captured network log and came to know that 
URL :`http://myhostname/Home/GetProfile/11` 
Result : Aborted
Type :
Initiator : ActiveX Control Initialization.

If I access the same application in Chrome, chrome loads PDF without any issue but IE9 is not able to load PDF.

Below is the code.

### Criteria Page

```
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id ="frmReport" method="get" action='@Url.Action("Report","Home")' 
target="iReport">
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Click"/>
            </form>
            <iframe id="iReport" name="iReport"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
```

In above iReport iframe will get Result HTML which has object tag

### Report Viewer html code.

```
    <div id="reportContainer">
    @{string urlPDF = "http://myhostname" + @Url.Action("GetProfile", 
              "Home", new { Id = "11" });
      <object id = "pdfView" height="600px" width="100%" 
type='application/pdf' data='@urlPDF'>
      </object>}
    </div>
```

### Code in MVC application.

```
public FileStreamResult GetProfile(string Id)
{
    var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "Profile.pdf",
        Inline = true
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
    byte[] bytes = ReportStore.GetProfileInByte(Id);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

Tried FileContentResult in place pf FileStreamResult and problem is same.

Do anyone know what is the problem with IE9? I traced the Application the request responded by server do not have any problem area, but  IE9-PDF ActiveX is not handling content rendering, anyone knows what could be the reason?

Not only this but when I tried in our couple of machines the result is same disappointing.
Machines are having IE9 and AdobePDFReder 9\10. Everywhere with VS.Net Debugger things are working but once coming out from debugger things starts failing.

Thanks

Comment: Machines were I tried I missed to provide PDF Servicesource. But Seems issues with IE9 and Adobe PDF Reader ActiveX control on my browser only, I took couple of Desktop(s) which has IE9/IE8 and Adobe Acrobat Reader 9/10 same no issues loading the PDF. Investigating whats is problem with ActiveX on my Browser.

Comment: IE9 64 bit has problem to render PDF in Acrobat Reader. Adobe should release fix in new aversion or as an update to existing version.